# Dart Convert two Uint8 to Uint16 that are little endian

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to dart but I need to take two Uint8 (part of a bluetooth response) and convert them to a single Uint16.  They are also in little endian (LSB) so the second value will need to shift 8 bytes.  I am struggling on how to do this in Dart.

I have tried something like this but it isn't coming close as the values are too high.

```
var list = new Uint8List(2);
list[0] = 56;
list[1] = 55;
int intValue = list[0] + (list[1] << 8);
Uint16 int16Value = Uint16(intValue);
print(int16Value);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `ByteData` from the list and `ByteData` has all sorts of functions for changing endianess and getting different integer types, more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html#instance-methods).

```dart
var data = list.buffer.asByteData();
print(data.getUint16(0, Endian.little));
```