# Different values being returned on Flutter Blue Plus

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm using the example code from the [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus). I can connect to the device and read the data stream as an array:

[90, 0, 0, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **45**, **5**, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 91, 118, 90]

```
void onNewReceivedData(List<int> data) {
_numberOfMessagesReceived += 1;
_receivedData.add( "$_numberOfMessagesReceived: $data" as int);
if (_receivedData.length > 5) {
  _receivedData.removeAt(0);
}
print(_receivedData.join("\n"));
refreshScreen();
```

}

But they are not the correct numbers. I've contacted the manufacturer of the Bluetooth module I'm trying to use, and he told me It's correct and sent me this:

Low byte 45 = 0x2D

High byte 05 = 0x05

0x052D = 1325 = 13.2V

The manufacturer is Chinese, and we are stuck in a big language barrier here; I've been using google translate to translate his emails, but most of it makes no sense to me. Do you happen to know what he is talking about?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: It's very hard to understand what your code is doing. What is `data` here (how did you get it)? What is `_receivedData`? What is the meaning of the "string `as int`" construction? Why are you removing a single element every time the length is greater than 5? What do you expect the output to be? How is it related to the array you've shown here? The buffer looks fine; I agree with your manufacturer, but we need the BLE service and characteristic you're reading to help you decode it correctly. Is this a standard profile, or something custom?

Comment: I think I figure it out, It's a hexadecimal value if you convert 45 in hexadecimal = 0x2D and if you convert 05 in hexa = 0x05, combine the 2 together 0x052D then convert back to decimal you get the correct number 1325 then divide by 100 to get the voltage of 13.2V

so I'll just have to figure out how to get the hexadecimal value instead of decimal out of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the part that was confusing you. You're trying to build a value from a 16-bit little-endian value. I'm guessing the result is then in centivolts (1/100 volt). (It would be much easier to answer if you would include what service this is using.)

If you have already pulled out the values, 45 and 5, then this is how you turn that into a complete value:

```
const low = 45;
const high = 5;
const volts = ((high << 8) + low) / 100; // 13.25
```

This shifts `high` left 8 bits (to make it the most-significant byte), adds `low` (as the least-significant byte), and divides the entire value by 100 to get volts.

There is no significance to whether these values are represented in hexadecimal or decimal. Those are just different ways of writing down numbers. It has no impact on what the numbers actually are.

See also [Dart Convert two Uint8 to Uint16 that are little endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445283/dart-convert-two-uint8-to-uint16-that-are-little-endian) for how to do this directly out of a Uint8List.